# How to open destination window on nav_graph android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I mistakenly closed window with destinations in navigation graph and i have no idea how to open it again.[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtLzz.png)

[And i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn3VQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose this one

[image: button]

and then add the fragment which you want. Or add new fragment and then this menu will recreate